# Photo upload field on Account Information page

Tags: event-observer, controllers, upload

What would be the best and approach of adding photo upload field on customer's Account Information page?

I tried to use events 'customer_save_before' and 'customer_save_after' but they didn't fire at the right time and the temporary file was already gone.

I tried to override AccountController.php which processes form data but for some reason my override code in custom module doesn't work.

Is there any other relatively simple way to achieve this without overriding core files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to solve issue like this is to debug.

First log all event that is dispatch when a customer account is created. See [Choosing a right event to observe](http://inchoo.net/magento/choosing-a-right-event-to-observe/)

Then just add another log at various location to check if the uploaded image still existed see `createPostAction()` in  /app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php

Then check your log file to see at what point the (temp) image was deleted and all event that was dispatch before.